# Dissolve adjacent parts of multipolygon into a single Polygon

Tags: qgis, postgis, dissolve, multipart

I have a multipolygon with two parts:

[image]

I want to erase the line that separate both parts and get a single polygon that looks like this:

[image]

I don't mind if I do it in QGIS or in Postgis, but it has to be only for this multipolygon.

I have read similar posts that suggest a solution to the problem but I had no success so far. I read and tried [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64941/postgis-dissolve-union-close-polygons), [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65256/merge-intersecting-polygons-into-one-which-are-part-of-the-same-feature/65261#65261) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43866/merging-multipolygon-data-into-a-polygon).

I tried  postgis functions like ST_Dump, ST_Collect, ST_ConvexHull, St_Union, ST_ExteriorRing, ST_Boundary, etc in SQLs like:

```
update my_table set the_geom = ST_Boundary(st_snaptogrid(the_geom,0.0001))  where id=3173
```

I don't really know which is the right approach to achieve this.

PD: If I do ST_NumGeometries I obviously get 2 geometries.

Comment: It is not topologically possible to have a valid multipolygon with shared boundaries between parts. You may have a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a kind of hack but you can use ST_Buffer(geom,0)...

Proof of concept:

```
select 1 as id,
   ST_astext(ST_Buffer(ST_Geomfromtext('MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0)),((1 0,1 1,2 1,2 0,1 0)))'),0)) as way
```

id  way

1   POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,2 1,2 0,1 0,0 0))